Prevent duplicate colors in TColorDialog
When using a TColorDialog in Delphi I want to prevent a custom color (lower pane on the left) that is already in the basic colors (upper pane on the left) from being displayed. I would expect that the dialog takes care of this when adding a custom color, but it doesn't.
My idea then was to test the custom color against the basic colors in the code and only add it if it wasn't a basic color. Again, this does not seem to be possible as there is no way to get the basic colors from the dialog. So I can't test if the custom color is a basic color in the dialog.
Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired behavior?

"but it doesn't" - it never did so since its invention. I understood the "custom colors" always as "custom selection/favorites" and as such would be disappointed to not add any color on purpose. Hooking the CHOOSECOLOR doesn't give you any notification option on that either.

Yes, this dialog has not been updated or changed since Windows 95, released in 1995. During the last 30 years, it has been used in thousands, if not millions, of Windows applications. If it would behave differently in your app, compared to all other apps, the user may be quite confused. It may be a better idea to create your own, custom dialog. Then you can also make it a bit more modern. The Windows 95 dialog is somewhat dated today.

Still think this is a design fault not showing the currently selected color in this dialog by default. But enabling the cdFullOpen option shows at least the currently selected color. So this is what I go for. Thanks.
